# Doing a simple math equation from a file using echo or cat

Tags: math, echo, cat

As simple as this question may be I for some reason can't figure it out for the life of me or find any other thing similar I could work off of. I have a text file with one simple multiplication in it which is 2*3. Using cat and echo commands only with the use of piping and arithmetic expansions allowed as well I am to print the solution of that equation. Below is what I am trying and have tried so far along with the error messages that have come with it. If and for loops cannot be used either. It must also be all in one line.

**multiply.txt**

```
2*3
```

**Code & error message**

```
cat multiply.txt | echo $($(multiply.txt)) 
./multiply.txt: line 1: 2*3: command not found

echo $($(multiply.txt)
./multiply.txt: line 1: 2*3: command not found
```

**Desired Output**

```
6
```

Comment: vim is the text editor i was using to create the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
echo $((`cat multiply.txt`))
```

Comment: to use Bret's notation, it's `echo $(($(cat multiply.txt)))`, i.e., he just missed one set of parentheses

Comment: Perfect exactly what i was looking for. Cant believe it was just one set of missed parentheses that was causing this whole issue i feel silly now >_<

Comment: It's not entirely just one set of missed parens, the `cat` was also added to the interior.

Comment: The same, but slightly shorter and a tad faster : `echo $(( $(< multiply.txt) ))` because you avoid the use of `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. Be advised that the proposed solution will only work with integer arithmetic. A bit better would be to make use of `bc`:

```
$ cat math.txt
5*6
sqrt(2)*3
pi=4*a(1)
c(pi/3)
$ bc -l < math.txt
30
4.24264068711928514640
.50000000000000000001
```